# Map Set of objects to Set of strings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mapstruct

I'm new at MapStruct.
I have a Word object that contains a string value and a set of itself and I want to map it to WordDTO that contains a value and set of string values. and I have no idea how to do that.
As I said in the comments it makes sense that mapstruct can't map two objects but if it helps I put the error below:
`Error:(20,13) java: Can't map property "java.util.Set<Word> synonyms" to "java.util.Set<java.lang.String> synonyms". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.Set<java.lang.String> map(java.util.Set<Word> value)"`

Word class:

```
public class Word {
    private String wordValue;
    private Set<Word> synonyms;
}
```

WordDTO class:

```
public class WordDTO {
    private String wordValue;
    private Set<String> synonyms;
}
```

(actually set or list... it doesn't matter at all.)

I implemented this interface for mapping:

```
@Mapper
public interface WordMapper {
    WordMapper INSTANCE= Mappers.getMapper(WordMapper.class);

    WordDTO wordToWordDTO(Word word);
    Word wordDTOToWord(WordDTO wordDTO);
}
```

thank you for your helping.

Comment: What about `synonyms.stream().map(Word::getWordValue).collect(Collectors.toSet())`?

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev MapStruct is a code generator for creating efficient, type-safe bean-to-bean mappings in Java.

Comment: What errors do you get when using the mapper?

Comment: @dan1st this will absolutly correct... but because of some reasons I want mapstruct generate this code in compile time. Problem is I don't know where should I put it. Maybe something like custome generator?

Comment: @JohnMercier It makes sense that we can't map object to string.//ERROR//                                Error:(20,13) java: Can't map property "java.util.Set<@javax.validation.Valid com.teimour.wordsaver.domain.Word> synonyms" to "java.util.Set<java.lang.String> synonyms". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.Set<java.lang.String> map(java.util.Set<@javax.validation.Valid com.teimour.wordsaver.domain.Word> value)".

Comment: Can you add the error to your question to make it easier for others to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapstruct is complaining that he cannot convert `Word` to `String`. You have to tell explicitly the mapper how to do it.

Here is an example:

```java
@Mapper
public interface WordMapper {
    WordMapper INSTANCE= Mappers.getMapper(WordMapper.class);

    WordDTO wordToWordDTO(Word word);
    Word wordDTOToWord(WordDTO wordDTO);

    // Map String to Word
    @Mapping(source = "value", target = "wordValue")
    Word stringToWord(String value)

    // Map Word to string
    default String wordToString(Word word) {
      return (word == null) ? null : word.getWordValue();
    }
   
}
```